# Adding a single HD to an existing RAID-1 configuration. How to proceed?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning, raid

We currently have two HP server with 2 HD mounted as RAID-1, running with Ubuntu 16.04. As end of support approached for Ubuntu16, we decided to move to Ubuntu 20.04, but we want to run several tests in the testing server before deploying Ubuntu 20 in the production server.

Since the test server is also used as a backup platform in case of failure of the operational one, we want to minimize the amount of time that this server switch is not possible due to having different OS versions.

Hence, we are considering adding a single HD to the test server, in order to install Ubuntu 20 in a new partition, and allowing the user to run either with existing Ubuntu 16 partition or with the new Ubuntu 20 partition.

Once the validation process is over, we would format the existing RAID-1 and leave only Ubuntu 20.04, so we would not be using the new HD any more. I mean: I do not need the new HD to be integrated into the RAID-1 for redundancy, it is just a temporary solution.

So, is this possible? Do I need to take any special consideration, or is it as simple as inserting the HD in its slot, running Ubuntu 20 installer, and the new HD will be detected as an empty, unformatted HD? Do I need to configure anything at all at the server BIOS (which I guess it isn't even called like that in a server)?

Comment: Why wouldn’t the firmware of a server be called he BIOS, it’s still a computer, and would still be called BIOS (or UEFI depending on the age of the hardware).

Comment: Welcome to superuser.  Unfortunately your question shows you don't know how much you don't know in this regard, and your question can't be answered as is. We need A LOT more detail - starting off with are you using hardware or software raid. How are your disk partitioned. I confess to not understanding your migration strategy - why not just disconnect the RAID and do testing on the non raid disk?

Comment: @davidgo Can I do that? Extract the current disks composing the RAID-1 and not losing the data due to the lack of power?

Comment: Definitely you won't lose them due to lack of power. If its software RAID you can do it. (I'm not qualified to talk in hardware RAID).  There is 1 gotcha I can think of - if you are using UEFI boot rather then Legacy mode you may have some fisling to do with the boot up because UEFI injects boot instructions into the IEFI (BIOS).  It should still work, buy may present a phantom boot option until its cleaned up.